# How can I specify a column to fill an Excel Combobox?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

First time asking here, so sorry if you find it annoying.
I've been trying to fill a ComboBox in an Excel Sheet with the result set of a DB procedure. So far, I've received the result set correctly, but when I try to specify the column I'd like to use to set the combo box values (3rd of the response), it keeps using the id's (1st column), even when I'm using the .BoundColumn command as follows:

```vb
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "mySP"

Set rst = cmd.Execute()

With rst
    i = .Fields.Count
    vData = .GetRows
End With

With Sheet1
    With .ComboBoxP
        .Clear
        .BoundColumn = 3
        .List = Application.Transpose(vData)
        .ListIndex = -1
    End With
    .ComboBoxP.Text = "-- Pick one --"
End With
```

Is there something wrong with the command order that makes the code to use always the same column? May it be an Excel version issue (I'm using MS Excel 2010 in spanish)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `TextColumn` property for setting which value gets shown to the user. The `BoundColumn` property sets which value your code gets when it reads the Value property of the control after the user has made a selection.